# Implementing a JavaC compiler plugin that runs after all analysis is done

Tags: java, javac

I'm writing a plug in that builds some auxiliary data during the analysis phase, and once all files/classes are analyzed, I want to run a process over all my data.

The compiler framework today only sends (via TaskListener) `ANALYZE` and `GENERATE` events, one per compile unit. I'm surprised that I get `ANALYZE` then `GENERATE` events per compile unit, vs all `ANALYZE` events, then followed by all `GENERATE` events.

What I'd like is a single event that says "all analysis is done", but there doesn't seem to be such an event.

What is the right way to do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hit this issue as well, thinking that if I compile 10 classes, I would get each phase for each file, but that's not how it works.  It is compiling one file at a time, so you get all the events for each at once.  I found that if you control the process that is doing the compile (i.e. you are running javac from java), then you can collect all the ANALYZE events while compiler is running, and then process them after compilation finishes.

Then, if you want to emit new source, you do so, run the compiler again yourself, and keep going until your output is stable.

It's ...not great.  I've also had to wire up my own set of callbacks for "oh, I need to wait until these three classes are analyzed / etc", so each analysis can subscribe to what it needs, and then when those types are encountered, run your callbacks then.

Perhaps there are better strategies out there, but I saw this lonely question and didn't want to leave it without some hints about how I've approached the issues.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Yeah, there doesn't seem to be anything great here. The Java Compiler APIs are ... lacking. Thanks though!